# Blank login page for apache Guacamole (docker install)

Tags: docker, guacamole

I installed guacamole docker using this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZB4msyOaUs

Everything worked fine but I'm just getting a blank page when browsing to http://ip-machine:8080/guacamole
However server returns some data as 'view as source' shows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Apache license ...
-->
<html ng-app="index" ng-controller="indexController">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi"/>
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo-64.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="144x144" href="images/logo-144.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo-144.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css?v=1.0.0">
        <title ng-bind="page.title | translate"></title>
    </head>
    <body ng-class="page.bodyClassName">

        <!-- Content for logged-in users -->
        <div ng-if="!expectedCredentials">
        
            <!-- Global status/error dialog -->
            <div ng-class="{shown: guacNotification.getStatus()}" class="status-outer">
                <div class="status-middle">
                    <guac-notification notification="guacNotification.getStatus()"></guac-notification>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="content" ng-view>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <!-- Login screen for logged-out users -->
        <guac-login ng-show="expectedCredentials"
                    help-text="loginHelpText"
                    form="expectedCredentials"
                    values="acceptedCredentials"></guac-login>

        <!-- Reformat URL for AngularJS if query parameters are present -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="relocateParameters.js"></script>

        <!-- Utility libraries -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/lodash/4.17.10/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>

        <!-- AngularJS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/angular/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/angular-route/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/angular-touch/1.6.9/angular-touch.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Internationalization -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/messageformat/1.0.2/messageformat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/angular-translate/2.16.0/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/2.16.0/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/angular-translate-loader-static-files/2.16.0/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Polyfills for the "datalist" element, Blob and the FileSaver API -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/blob-polyfill/1.0.20150320/Blob.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/datalist-polyfill/1.14.0/datalist-polyfill.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/filesaver/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Allow arbitrary ordering of Angular module creation and retrieval -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/angular-module-shim/0.0.4/angular-module-shim.js"></script>

        <!-- Web application -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js?v=1.0.0"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

catalina.out does not report any error (I was expecting some DB related error, but no), localhost_access_log neither:

```js
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4534
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/relocateParameters.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4505
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/app.css?v=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 53239
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/messageformat/1.0.2/messageformat.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 49339
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/angular-route/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5611
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/angular-translate/2.16.0/angular-translate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 24141
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 87020
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/lodash/4.17.10/dist/lodash.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 73233
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/angular-touch/1.6.9/angular-touch.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4074
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/angular/1.6.9/angular.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 170093
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/angular-translate-loader-static-files/2.16.0/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1369
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/datalist-polyfill/1.14.0/datalist-polyfill.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5787
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/2.16.0/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1447
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/blob-polyfill/1.0.20150320/Blob.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6148
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/filesaver/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2446
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/webjars/angular-module-shim/0.0.4/angular-module-shim.js HTTP/1.1" 200 774
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/app.js?v=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 334930
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/fonts/carlito/Carlito-Regular.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 269832
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/api/patches HTTP/1.1" 200 352
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/api/languages HTTP/1.1" 200 151
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/translations/en.json HTTP/1.1" 200 40710
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/translations/fr.json HTTP/1.1" 200 28579
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/images/progress.png HTTP/1.1" 200 473
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/images/guac-tricolor.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14890
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/fonts/carlito/Carlito-Italic.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 283500
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:49 +0000] "GET /guacamole/fonts/carlito/Carlito-Bold.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 281212
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:23:55 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:28:12 +0000] "POST /guacamole/api/tokens HTTP/1.1" 500 183
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:34:17 +0000] "GET /guacamole/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4534
```

Any idea?
Thanks,
BTW, http://ip-machine:8080 is properly showing tomcat page.
Jean

Comment: I can clearly see that you got `172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:07:28:12 +0000] "POST /guacamole/api/tokens HTTP/1.1" 500 183
` and guacamole uses tokens for every action so it may have something to do with it, anyways, i can recommend you to install guacamole from here : https://github.com/boschkundendienst/guacamole-docker-compose This has worked the best for me after few docker installs that made issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know what I did wrong exactly, but now it is working fine.